# apt-get bricked by nvidia drivers

Tags: apt, nvidia

I was updating my machine while some drivers crashed. After the reboot my X server was broken and I have reinstalled it.

Now `apt-get` is stuck with this error:

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo apt-get install -f                                                                                                                                                       0 < 15:56:15
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxnvctrl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  glx-alternative-nvidia
Suggested packages:
  nvidia-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  glx-alternative-nvidia
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package glx-alternative-nvidia.
(Reading database ... 385691 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../glx-alternative-nvidia_0.8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking glx-alternative-nvidia (0.8.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of glx-alternative-nvidia:
 glx-alternative-nvidia depends on glx-diversions (= 0.8.0); however:
  Package glx-diversions is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package glx-alternative-nvidia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-alternative:
 nvidia-alternative depends on glx-alternative-nvidia (>= 0.7); however:
  Package glx-alternative-nvidia is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-alternative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glx-alternative-nvidia
 nvidia-alternative
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried these commands:

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo apt-get remove glx-alternative-nvidia glx-diversions nvidia-alternative                                                                                                  0 < 16:15:48
[sudo] password for phra: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl-nvidia0 : Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-4) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx-nvidia0 : Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-4) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ml1 : Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-4) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-vdpau-driver : Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.82-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 375.82-4) but it is not going to be installed or
                                   nvidia-kernel-375.82
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo apt-get install -f glx-diversions                                                                                                                                        0 < 16:22:54
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
glx-diversions is already the newest version (0.8.0).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxnvctrl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of glx-alternative-nvidia:
 glx-alternative-nvidia depends on glx-diversions (= 0.8.0); however:
  Package glx-diversions is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package glx-alternative-nvidia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-alternative:
 nvidia-alternative depends on glx-alternative-nvidia (>= 0.7); however:
  Package glx-alternative-nvidia is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-alternative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glx-alternative-nvidia
 nvidia-alternative
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo dpkg --configure -a                                                                                                                                                      0 < 16:23:15
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of glx-alternative-nvidia:
 glx-alternative-nvidia depends on glx-diversions (= 0.8.0); however:
  Package glx-diversions is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package glx-alternative-nvidia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-alternative:
 nvidia-alternative depends on glx-alternative-nvidia (>= 0.7); however:
  Package glx-alternative-nvidia is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-alternative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glx-alternative-nvidia
 nvidia-alternative
```

Do you know how I can fix the situation?

EDIT:

I've fixed apt but I'm not able to restore gnome.

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo service gdm3 status                                                                                                                                     0 < 18:49:41
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 17 18:50:27 kali gdm-launch-environment][10388]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm by (uid=0)
Oct 17 18:50:35 kali gdm3[10379]: Child process -10392 was already dead.
Oct 17 18:50:35 kali gdm3[10379]: Child process 10388 was already dead.
Oct 17 18:50:35 kali gdm3[10379]: Unable to kill session worker process
Oct 17 18:50:35 kali gdm-launch-environment][10431]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm by (uid=0)
Oct 17 18:50:47 kali systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
Oct 17 18:50:47 kali gdm3[10379]: GLib: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Oct 17 18:50:47 kali gdm3[10379]: GLib: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Oct 17 18:50:47 kali gdm3[10379]: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
Oct 17 18:50:47 kali systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's the command to unbrick apt

```
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/glx-diversions_0.7.4_amd64.deb 0 < 17:47:06
[sudo] password for phra: 
(Reading database ... 385701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../glx-diversions_0.7.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking glx-diversions (0.7.4) over (0.8.0) ...
dpkg: glx-diversions: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
glx-diversions depends on glx-alternative-mesa (= 0.7.4); however:
Version of glx-alternative-mesa on system is 0.8.0.
libgl1:amd64 (0.2.999+git20170802-5) breaks glx-diversions (<< 0.8) and is installed.
Version of glx-diversions to be configured is 0.7.4.

Setting up glx-diversions (0.7.4) ...
Removing diverted 'libGL.so.1' symlink with unexpected target 'libGL.so.1.0.0'.
Restoring diverted 'libGL.so.1' symlink.
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (0.8.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-17) ...
╭─phra at kali in /home/phra
╰─λ sudo apt-get install -f                                                                                                                                                       0 < 18:13:19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxnvctrl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  glx-diversions
The following packages will be upgraded:
  glx-diversions
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 385727 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../glx-diversions_0.8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking glx-diversions (0.8.0) over (0.7.4) ...
Setting up glx-diversions (0.8.0) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (0.8.0) ...
Setting up glx-alternative-nvidia (0.8.0) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (0.8.0) ...
Setting up nvidia-alternative (375.82-4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-17) ...
Processing triggers for update-glx (0.8.0) ...
Processing triggers for nvidia-alternative (375.82-4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia/current to provide /usr/lib/nvidia/nvidia (nvidia) in auto mode
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (0.8.0) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia to provide /usr/lib/glx (glx) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-17) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-kali1-amd64
WARNING: Setting CRYPTSETUP in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Use /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook instead.
```